# Area of Portion of Sphere from a inside Cube

Tags: area

The late painter Maqbool Fida Husain once coloured the surface of a huge hollow steel sphere, of radius $1$ metre, using just two colours, Red and Blue. As was his style however, both the red and blue areas were a bunch of highly irregular disconnected regions. The late sculptor Ramkinkar Baij then tried to fit in a cube inside the sphere, the eight vertices of the cube touching only red coloured parts of the surface of the sphere. Assume $\pi=3.14$ for solving this problem. Which of the following is true?

A)Baij is bound to succeed if the area of the red part is $10 sq. metres$;

B)Baij is bound to fail if the area of the red part is $10 sq. metres$;

C)Baij is bound to fail if the area of the red part is $11 sq. metres$;

D)Baij is bound to succeed if the area of the red part is $11 sq. metres$;

E)None of the above.

---

My solution is:
Here given , radius of sphere  $r=1m.$

So, $d=2m.$

Now, say side of a cube is $a$ $m.$

So, diagonal of a square $a\sqrt{2}m.$

[image]

Now, see using Pythagoras Theorem

$a^{2}+\left ( a\sqrt{2} \right )^{2}=2^{2}$

$\Rightarrow a=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$

Now, we have to divide the sphere such a way $a=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ is maximum cord.

Check the diagram, where red area inscribe the cube. and blue area outside the cube.

[image]
Now see the sphere divided inside hollow region of the cube in $6$ equal parts (1,2,3,4, shown as in diagram and 5th one in front and 6th one is back. )

So, we can say , it takes the (area of cube+$\frac{5}{6}$ . area of hollow sphere) [As only upper side of cube is blue region.]

So, area of cube$=6\times \left ( \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \right )^{2}=8m.$

Now $\frac{5}{6}$ of hollow region of sphere $\left ( 4\pi \left ( 1 \right )^{2}-6\left ( \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \right )^{2} \right )\times \frac{5}{6}=3.809$

So, total area will be $=8+3.809=11.809m.$

So, nearest option will be $D)$ or exactly $E)$

---

Is this correct approach?

Comment: https://gateoverflow.in/25387/tifr2013-a-5

Comment: @WillJagy haha, that is me only :). I want to know, is my approach correct?

Comment: @WillJagy Is the ans correct?